# Mysql connection With magento is unstable after upgrade

Tags: magento2

I am a beginner in magento. I have enabled the extension on my store.
After upgrade and compile,the mysql connection became unstable.
I have to start connection every time
Can anyone provide a solution

Comment: what error are you facing?

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Comment: did you made changes in apache config file?

Comment: Check if mysql is running or not, if not run it

Comment: OR change the host=localhost to host=127.0.0.1. 
& by putting 'port' => '8889', in 'Datasources'

Comment: @Pramod No, I didnt make any changes to apache file

Comment: @HamendraSunthwal host already changes to 127.0.0.1, I restarted mysql it is again dropping

Comment: have you changed port ?

Comment: Where Can i edit it .In env.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `app/etc/env.php` and change `'host' => 'localhost'` to `'host' => '127.0.0.1'`. Also run `setup:upgrade` command.

Comment: Already changed  and ran setup:upgrade

Comment: I had same issue but this fix solved it.

Comment: losing connection while compile

Comment: 2020-12-11T10:11:48.355887Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2020-12-11T10:11:48.356116Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2020-12-11T10:11:48.356132Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2020-12-11T10:11:48.356650Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2020-12-11T10:11:48.356665Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2020-12-11T10:11:48.357957Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2020-12-11T10:11:48.364822Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2020-12-11T10:11:48.366417Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

Comment: from my sql error log